# Pandas read_csv() works on CSV file in Python 3 but returns NaNs in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

A simple, yet somewhat baffling enquiry. I have a CSV file, which originally contains 136 rows and 24 columns of data (plus a column of indices and two rows' worth of column headers). When I import this file into Python with the aid of pandas, everything is okay both in Python 3 and Python 2.

```
import pandas as pd

R = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv', index_col=0, header=[0,1])
```

However, things go south when I reorder the CSV, compacting eight old file rows into a single new row. This results in 17 rows and 192 columns of data, which Python 3's pandas still handles fine. However, Python 2's pandas now just returns a giant data frame of NaNs, with the indices/column names imported fine.

Any idea what's going on here? How do I make it go away? I need this code to work in Python 2 because reasons. In case it's of relevance, Python 2 is on Debian.

Comment: Can you post the smallest version of the CSV that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: Here is the file that's been causing the trouble: https://github.com/ktpolanski/ip2/blob/master/gp2s_demo_file/demo2new.csv

Comment: I dunno, but it reads in fine for me with python 2.7.8 and pandas 0.16.1.  I just used `pd.read_csv(filename)` without any options.

Comment: Beautiful, works. Apparently I was on pandas 0.14.1 because apt-get life on the Debian, but an upgrade through pip sorted this out. Many thanks! No idea what was wrong in 0.14.1, but apparently it got sorted out by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stemmed from an outdated pandas version (0.14.1), which is distributed through apt-get on Debian. Updating pandas through pip to 0.17.1 solved the issue, so whatever bug caused this got sorted out by now. Thanks to JohnE for the help!